# How to trim a FBX animation file?

Tags: animation, export

I have a fbx animation file of a lot different soccer player's movements(downloaded from an asset store), and I want to create smaller FBX files of certain animations(the ones I need).
I am able to import the file into blender and am able to find the range of keyframes I want, but I am not sure how to select and or export and save that specific range as a new fbx file.

I installed blender today, so please be a little detailed if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first select all the objects with <kbd>A</kbd>

> In case you want only specific objects to be exported, select those objects with <kbd>Left-click</kbd>, to *add* more objects to selection, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left-click</kbd>

On the *Timeline* window you will see multiple white squares *(keyframes)*

[image: Keyframes]

By scrolling the <kbd>MMB</kbd> you *zoom IN/OUT* on the timeline

While hovering over the Timeline tab, hit <kbd>B</kbd>, a checkered cross will appear allowing for click and drag selection

[image: B]

Select the keyframes you want to delete

[image: Selection_1]

For further selection, hit <kbd>B</kbd> again and select another set of keyframes

[image: Selection_2]

And hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Then just navigate to *File > Export > FBX*

[image: delete]

> In case of exporting only selected objects, make sure you check the
> ***Selected Objects*** checkbox
>
> [image: Export]

**Done!**

When imported again, you should only get the keyframes from the desired part.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I was looking for trimming an animation file in terms of time. For example, the file I have is around 10 min long but I dont need all that, I only need the animation that plays at the 6th min.

Comment: Alright, understand. I edited the answer so it should explain more accurately! ;)